# How do I add a NotificationListener to an MBean on WebSphere 7.  The listeners are never added to the mbean?

Tags: websphere, jmx

I'm trying to add a NotificationListener to listen for notifications from a registered MBean.

Through my setup of the MBean, I *can* connect to my WAS7 test environment, and see/manage my 'HelloMBean'.  Also, I can call methods on it via the `com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClient`. I've created a test listener class:

```
/**
     * Inner class that will handle the notifications.
     */
    public static class ClientListener implements NotificationListener {
        public void handleNotification(Notification notification, Object handback) {
            RasMessage rasMessage = (RasMessage) notification.getUserData();
            System.out.println("Localized message: " + rasMessage.getLocalizedMessage(null));
            System.out.println("\nReceived notification:");
            System.out.println("\tClassName: " + notification.getClass().getName());
            System.out.println("\tSource: " + notification.getSource());
            System.out.println("\tType: " + notification.getType());
            System.out.println("\tMessage: " + notification.getMessage());
            if (notification instanceof AttributeChangeNotification) {
                AttributeChangeNotification acn = (AttributeChangeNotification) notification;
                System.out.println("\tAttributeName: " + acn.getAttributeName());
                System.out.println("\tAttributeType: " + acn.getAttributeType());
                System.out.println("\tNewValue: " + acn.getNewValue());
                System.out.println("\tOldValue: " + acn.getOldValue());
            }
        }

    }
```

The steps I take are:

- Create MBean
- Register MBean (I can see it on the console).
- Then, with the correct ObjectName, I try to add the notification listener three
  different ways

All of these never call addNotificationListener on the MBean

```
ClientListener listener = new ClientListener();
                adminClient.addNotificationListenerExtended(objectName, listener, null, null);
                adminClient.addNotificationListener(objectName, listener, null, null);
                    AdminServiceFactory.getMBeanFactory().getMBeanServer().addNotificationListener(MBeanServerDelegate.DELEGATE_NAME, listener, null, null);
```

I then call the method on the MBean that should send a notification.

The problem is that, in the NotificationBroadcasterSupport.sendNotification(), that there aren't any listeners on the listener list for this MBean.

I'm guessing that the 'addNotificationListener()' method on the mbean should get called when I try to add it in the previous steps, but it **never does**

Any thoughts?

I'm also trying to manually add them, which isn't working as well:

//interface

```
public interface HelloMBean extends TUFMBean {

public void addNotificationListener(NotificationListener listener, NotificationFilter filter, Object handback);

public abstract String getName();

public abstract int getCacheSize();

public abstract void setCacheSize(int size);

public abstract void sayHello();

public abstract int add(int x, int y);

public abstract MBeanNotificationInfo[] getNotificationInfo();

public String getIdentification();

public void initialize(Object paramObject);
```

}

//impl:

```
   package cat.dcs.core.services.mbean;

import javax.management.AttributeChangeNotification;
import javax.management.MBeanNotificationInfo;
import javax.management.Notification;
import javax.management.NotificationBroadcasterSupport;
import javax.management.NotificationFilter;
import javax.management.NotificationListener;

import junitx.util.PrivateAccessor;

public class HelloNotificationImpl extends NotificationBroadcasterSupport implements HelloMBean {

    private String name = "HelloMBean";
    private int cacheSize = DEFAULT_CACHE_SIZE;
    private static final int DEFAULT_CACHE_SIZE = 200;
    private long sequenceNumber = 1;


    public HelloNotificationImpl() {
        System.out.println(">>>>> CONSTRUCTOR " + this);
    }

    /*
     * *************************************************** 
     * TUFMBeanImpl req's
     * ***************************************************
     */
    public HelloNotificationImpl(String paramString) {
        setIdentification(paramString);
    }

    private void setIdentification(String paramString) {
        name = paramString;
    }

    @Override
    public String getIdentification() {
        System.out.println(">>>>> getIdentification " + this);
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(Object paramObject) {
        System.out.println(">>>>> INIT "+ this);

    }

    @Override
    public void addNotificationListener(NotificationListener listener, NotificationFilter filter, Object handback) {
        System.out.println(">>>>> ADD NOTIFICATION LISTENER " + this);
        super.addNotificationListener(listener, filter, handback);

        try {
            System.out.println(PrivateAccessor.getField(this, "listenerList"));
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    /*
     * *************************************************** 
     * notification broadcaster use
     * ***************************************************
     */

    /**
     * TODO Update method documentation for Hello.setCacheSize Description of the method.
     * 
     * @param size
     * @see cat.cis.junk.x#setCacheSize(int)
     * @since 1.0 Jul 5, 2012 9:40:01 AM DudekTA
     */
    public synchronized void setCacheSize(int size) {
        System.out.println(">>>>> SET CACHE SIZE ON"+ this);

        int oldSize = cacheSize;
        cacheSize = size;

        System.out.println("Cache size now " + cacheSize);

        Notification n = new AttributeChangeNotification(this, sequenceNumber++, System.currentTimeMillis(),
                "CacheSize changed", "CacheSize", "int", oldSize, cacheSize);

        try {
            System.out.println(">>>LISTENER LIST ON MBEAN: " + PrivateAccessor.getField(this, "listenerList"));

        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        sendNotification(n);
    }

    /**
     * TODO Update method documentation for Hello.getNotificationInfo Description of the method.
     * 
     * @return
     * @since 1.0 Jul 5, 2012 9:40:01 AM DudekTA
     */
    @Override
    public MBeanNotificationInfo[] getNotificationInfo() {
        String[] types = new String[] { AttributeChangeNotification.ATTRIBUTE_CHANGE };

        String name = AttributeChangeNotification.class.getName();
        String description = "An attribute of this MBean has changed";
        MBeanNotificationInfo info = new MBeanNotificationInfo(types, name, description);
        return new MBeanNotificationInfo[] { info };
    }

    /*
     * *************************************************** 
     * test methods
     * ***************************************************
     */

    /**
     * TODO Update method documentation for Hello.sayHello Description of the method.
     * 
     * @see cat.cis.junk.x#sayHello()
     * @since 1.0 Jul 5, 2012 9:40:01 AM DudekTA
     */
    public void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("hello, world : " + this);
    }

    /**
     * TODO Update method documentation for Hello.add Description of the method.
     * 
     * @param x
     * @param y
     * @return
     * @see cat.cis.junk.x#add(int, int)
     * @since 1.0 Jul 5, 2012 9:40:01 AM DudekTA
     */
    public int add(int x, int y) {
        return x + y;
    }

    /**
     * TODO Update method documentation for Hello.getName Description of the method.
     * 
     * @return
     * @see cat.cis.junk.x#getName()
     * @since 1.0 Jul 5, 2012 9:40:01 AM DudekTA
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * TODO Update method documentation for Hello.getCacheSize Description of the method.
     * 
     * @return
     * @see cat.cis.junk.x#getCacheSize()
     * @since 1.0 Jul 5, 2012 9:40:01 AM DudekTA
     */
    public int getCacheSize() {
        return cacheSize;
    }

}
```

btw This isn't working either:

```
adminClient.invoke(objectName,"addNotificationListener" ,new Object[]{listener,null, null},new String[]{ "javax.management.NotificationListener","javax.management.NotificationFilter", "java.lang.Object" });
```

Adding XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<attribute name="name" getMethod="getName" type="java.lang.String"
    proxyInvokeType="unicall" />

<attribute name="cacheSize" getMethod="getCacheSize" type="int"
    setMethod="setCacheSize" proxyInvokeType="unicall" />

<operation name="sayHello" role="operation" type="void"
    targetObjectType="objectReference" impact="ACTION" proxyInvokeType="multicall">
    <signature>
    </signature>
</operation>


<operation name="add" role="operation" type="int"
    targetObjectType="objectReference" impact="ACTION" proxyInvokeType="multicall">
    <signature>
        <parameter name="x" description="x" type="int" />
        <parameter name="y" description="x" type="int" />
    </signature>
</operation>

<operation name="getNotificationInfo" role="operation" type="javax.management.MBeanNotificationInfo[]"
    targetObjectType="objectReference" impact="ACTION" proxyInvokeType="multicall">
    <signature>
    </signature>
</operation>

<operation name="addNotificationListener" role="operation" type="void"
    targetObjectType="objectReference" impact="ACTION" proxyInvokeType="multicall">
    <signature>
    <!-- javax.management.NotificationListener","javax.management.NotificationFilter", "java.lang.Object -->
        <parameter name="listener" description="javax.management.NotificationListener" type="javax.management.NotificationListener" />
        <parameter name="filter" description="javax.management.NotificationFilter" type="javax.management.NotificationFilter" />
        <parameter name="handback" description="java.lang.Object" type="java.lang.Object" />
    </signature>
</operation>
```

Basic Overview of steps:

```
[7/9/12 10:28:08:813 CDT] 00000017 SystemOut     O >>>>> CONSTRUCTOR cat.dcs.core.services.mbean.HelloNotificationImpl@7f4c7f4c
[7/9/12 10:28:08:813 CDT] 00000017 SystemOut     O >>>>> INIT cat.dcs.core.services.mbean.HelloNotificationImpl@7f4c7f4c
[7/9/12 10:28:08:813 CDT] 00000017 SystemOut     O >>>>> getIdentification cat.dcs.core.services.mbean.HelloNotificationImpl@7f4c7f4c
[7/9/12 10:28:08:820 CDT] 00000017 servlet       I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: [TestItEAR] [/TestIt] [TUFMBeanInitializerServlet]: Initialization successful.
[7/9/12 10:28:08:824 CDT] 00000017 SystemOut     O O1: [WebSphere:name=TestItEAR/TestIt.war/HelloMBean,TUFimpl=cat.dcs.core.services.mbean.HelloNotificationImpl,process=server1,TUFinterface=cat.dcs.core.services.mbean.HelloMBean,TUFtype=APPMBean,platform=dynamicproxy,node=C001460186Node02,version=7.0.0.17,type=HelloMBean,mbeanIdentifier=TestItEAR/TestIt.war/HelloMBean,cell=C001460186Node02Cell,spec=1.0]
[7/9/12 10:28:08:826 CDT] 00000017 SystemOut     O >>>>> TRYING TO ADD LISTENER
[7/9/12 10:28:08:826 CDT] 00000017 SystemOut     O hello, world : cat.dcs.core.services.mbean.HelloNotificationImpl@7f4c7f4c
[7/9/12 10:28:08:827 CDT] 00000017 SystemOut     O >>>> CALLING METHOD WITH NOTIFICATION
[7/9/12 10:28:08:827 CDT] 00000017 SystemOut     O >>>>> SET CACHE SIZE ONcat.dcs.core.services.mbean.HelloNotificationImpl@7f4c7f4c
[7/9/12 10:28:08:827 CDT] 00000017 SystemOut     O Cache size now 999
[7/9/12 10:28:08:829 CDT] 00000017 SystemOut     O >>>LISTENER LIST ON MBEAN: []
```

When sendNotification gets Called, There aren't any listeners.
[image: When sendNotification gets Called, There aren't any listeners.]

@Nicholas:
Not sure if this makes a difference?

> ```
> [7/9/12 14:00:48:811 CDT] 00000012 SystemOut     O >>>>> AC CLASSLOADER IS:
> ```
>
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader@3ae03ae
>   [7/9/12 14:00:48:812 CDT] 00000012 SystemOut     O O1:
>   [WebSphere:name=TestItEAR/TestIt.war/HelloMBean,TUFimpl=cat.dcs.core.services.mbean.HelloNotificationImpl,process=server1,TUFinterface=cat.dcs.core.services.mbean.HelloMBean,TUFtype=APPMBean,platform=dynamicproxy,node=C001460186Node02,version=7.0.0.17,type=HelloMBean,mbeanIdentifier=TestItEAR/TestIt.war/HelloMBean,cell=C001460186Node02Cell,spec=1.0]
>   [7/9/12 14:00:48:814 CDT] 00000012 SystemOut     O >>>>> TRYING TO ADD
>   LISTENER on this mbean below: [7/9/12 14:00:48:814 CDT] 00000012
>   SystemOut     O hello, world :
>   cat.dcs.core.services.mbean.HelloNotificationImpl@36c436c4 [7/9/12
>   14:00:48:814 CDT] 00000012 SystemOut     O >>>>> MY CLASSLOADER IS: 
>   com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader@586a586a[war:TestItEAR/TestIt.war]
>   Local ClassPath:
>   C:\workspace\TestIt\WebContent\WEB-INF\classes;C:\workspace\TestIt\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar;C:\workspace\TestIt\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\commons-codec-1.4.jar;C:\workspace\TestIt\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\commons-collections-3.2.1.jar;C:\workspace\TestIt\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\commons-discovery-0.2.jar;C:\workspace\TestIt\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar;C:\workspace\TestIt\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\commons-httpclient-3.1.jar;C:\workspace\TestIt\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\commons-io-1.4.jar;C:\workspace\TestIt\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\commons-lang-2.4.jar;C:\workspace\TestIt\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;C:\workspace\TestIt\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\commons-logging-adapters-1.1.1.jar;C:\workspace\TestIt\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\commons-logging-api-1.1.1.jar;C:\workspace\TestIt\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\commons-net-1.4.1.jar;C:\workspace\TestIt\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\jgl.jar;C:\workspace\TestIt\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\junit-addons-1.4.jar;C:\workspace\TestIt\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\tuf-common.jar;C:\workspace\TestIt\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\tuf-mbeans.jar;C:\workspace\TestIt\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\tuf-server.jar;C:\workspace\TestIt\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\tuf-web.jar;C:\workspace\TestIt\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\tuf-webservices.jar;C:\workspace\TestIt\WebContent
>   Parent:
>   com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader@56cb56cb[app:TestItEAR]
>   Delegation Mode: PARENT_FIRST

Where the classloader for the mbean, and the admin client are different?
: probably easier to read:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It will help if you post the code of your HelloMBean. Here's a few pointers:

Does it implement [NotificationBroadcaster](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/management/NotificationBroadcaster.html) or [NotificationEmitter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/management/NotificationEmitter.html) or extend [NotificationBroadcasterSupport](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/management/NotificationBroadcasterSupport.html) ?

Make sure the invoked method calls [sendNotification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/management/NotificationBroadcasterSupport.html#sendNotification%28javax.management.Notification%29).

It's also possible that (not sure with WAS) that the bean must publish [MBeanNotificationInfo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/management/MBeanNotificationInfo.html) in it's [MBeanInfo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/management/MBeanInfo.html) that describes the notifications that can be subscribed to.

Comment: Here's the implementation. Yes, it does extend NotificationBroadcasterSupport. you can see that 'setCacheSize' calls sendNotification, but there aren't any listeners on the listenerList.

Comment: As you said, there does not seem to be any output that looks like **>>>>> ADD NOTIFICATION LISTENER**. By any chance, are you registering the listener from a remote JVM, or from a different classloader ? It's possible that the AdminClient cannot fulfill the listener registration request because either A: The listener class is not serializable, and/or B: The listener class cannot be loaded by the MBean impl's classloader.

Comment: This is all the same jvm. On startup, the mbean gets registered via an abstraction that hides the websphere ' mbfactory.activateMBean()'. I added Serilizable to the listener, without progress.

Comment: Alright, reaching here.....  Have you scanned all the WAS logs to see if the MBeanServer kicked out any exceptions ? And for the heck of it, can you print out the MBean's and the listener's classloader when they're created ? Trying to determine if this is a classpath scoping issue.

Comment: fyi, everything is spit out to the console. I removed the abstraction and manually registered the mbean, and that didnt work, so i know it's not the process for 'activateMBean'.  Also, I don't know, but when I call: 
`adminClient.invoke(objectName,"addNotificationListener" ,new Object[]{listener,null, null},new String[]{ "javax.management.NotificationListener","javax.management.NotificationFilter", "java.lang.Object" });` it still wont execute addNotificationListener, like a regular method call, but I can execute 'sayHello' on the same objectname no prob right in a row

Comment: I tried adding `<notification name="jmx.attribute.change" severity="6" log="true"
  description="This sample state MBean changed.">
  <notificationType>jmx.attribute.change</notificationType>
 </notification>` to the mbean def, which also didnt work

Comment: I dunno tho', I would not go down the road of registering listeners directly. (You might be sorry later .....:) )   Uisng AdminClient's addNotificationListener(objectName, listener, null, null) is the right way to go. Just browsing AdminClient docs right now......

Comment: What about:
`adminClient.addNotificationListener(nodeAgent, this, null, null);` Where I am adding listeners via the objectName for the specific mbean, NOT the nodeagent. Also, now, I'm trying to find the node agent on a local WTE env.... This won't give me my nodeAgent "WebSphere:node=C001460186Node02,type=NodeAgent,*", which I thought it should

Comment: So it looks like that I have the standalone installation for websphere test environment, where there will not be a nodeagent:http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.ws.ast.st.common.ui.doc/topics/cwasnd.html Im not sure if this is why I cant add the listener? Funny that I can call all the methods on my mbean, but the addNotificationListener though

Answer (score 0):

So... How it worked out.

I changed from the RMI connection to the SOAP connection, and I could register the listener.

I don't know why the RMI connection allowed me to act on the MBean, but not set a listener, whereas I can do everything via the adminclient that uses the soap connection.

I don't have a good reason why, but that's how I fixed it.